# Is "natural step" a real expression?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-meaning, translation, expression-choice, phrase-requests

In my mother tongue, we sometimes express that the next "Natural step" can be to do something. However, this feels directly translated and not very accurate when expressed in English. Also, a Quick google search indicates to me that it is not commonly used in this context.

Do you recognize the expression?

If not, how could I describe that something would "naturally" be the next step in further development or investigation of something?

Comment: If it is widely accepted that step B comes after step A, you could say that B is the next logical step in the process. It could be an upgrade to go from step A to step B.

Comment: You can also just say "next step."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually English speakers would say the next ***logical step***.  As you pointed out, the phrase "natural step" isn't so common, although I don't think you would be misunderstood.

[image]

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=logical%20step%2Cnatural%20step&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clogical%20step%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnatural%20step%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: This one shows a little less disparity: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+logical+step+from%2Ca+natural+step+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20logical%20step%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20natural%20step%20from%3B%2Cc0